# Differences between source code and "inspect element"

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am currently coding a website which use CodeIgniter on a development server and everything is working perflecty (with all browsers) but when I host my website on the production server, only Firefox works like a charm, and others browsers are going wrong.

Here is what I got when I inspect element on Chrome:

[image]

On Internet Explorer 11 (production server) I have a strange char when I look for the source code (seems like a space or something like this) before the doctype which produce errors in the console

[image]

Development server and production server has the same version of PHP (5.5.33) and this is only happening on CodeIgniter pages.

Have you got some ideas of the problem ? Thank you very much

Comment: I think that the strange char before the doctype is the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Not really sure that all my directory is UTF8 (without BOM) encoded, if I found a solution to save in UTF8 without BOM the whole directory, the problem will be solved ?

Comment: (CodeIgniter use a lot of file and I can't check them all one by one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mapek who found the problem, I had a file which was saved in UTF8 with BOM, I saved it once again in UTF8 without BOM and it now works like a charm. Thank you !!